# regarding Typescript returning boolean from a function

Tags: angular, typescript, boolean

I want to return a boolean to function so I can use it on *ngIf. I am new with Angular and Typescript and want this to be done smoothly. Needs some assistance regarding this.

```
canView = false;



getView() {
    this.permissionService.getPermissionChecker('can_view_site', 'can_view_site').pipe(
      tap(res => {
        this.canView = true;
    );
  }
```

Template side

```
<app-site compact=true *ngIf="canView"></app-site>
```

Comment: what does getPermissionChecker function did?

Answer (score 0):

you can return the Observable, e.g. getView(): Observable and use the async pipe in ngIf

```
getView(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.permissionService.getPermissionChecker('can_view_site', 'can_view_site')
           .pipe(map(res => true (or false));
}

<div *ngIf="myObservable | async as myBoolean"></div>
```